# Trim just white spaces, but not linefeeds in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, trim, removing-whitespace

I want to trim just white spaces (0x20) from my string, but Dart's **trim** document says it will remove a set of characters:

````
Here is the list of trimmed characters according to Unicode version 6.3:
   * ```
   *     0009..000D    ; White_Space # Cc   <control-0009>..<control-000D>
   *     0020          ; White_Space # Zs   SPACE
   *     0085          ; White_Space # Cc   <control-0085>
   *     00A0          ; White_Space # Zs   NO-BREAK SPACE
   *     1680          ; White_Space # Zs   OGHAM SPACE MARK
   *     2000..200A    ; White_Space # Zs   EN QUAD..HAIR SPACE
   *     2028          ; White_Space # Zl   LINE SEPARATOR
   *     2029          ; White_Space # Zp   PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
   *     202F          ; White_Space # Zs   NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
   *     205F          ; White_Space # Zs   MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
   *     3000          ; White_Space # Zs   IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
   *
   *     FEFF          ; BOM                ZERO WIDTH NO_BREAK SPACE
````